# Jquery AJAX failing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send an ID to a PHP page to update a database. First time using AJAX.

I keep getting an error. The PHP file is in the same directory

```
function approve(id) {

        $.smallBox({
            title : "Are you sure you would like to approve this indicator?",
            content : "<p class='text-align-right'><a href='javascript:approve_indicator(" + id + ");' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'>Yes</a> <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>No</a></p>",
            color : "#296191",
            //timeout: 8000,
            icon : "fa fa-bell swing animated"
        });


}

function approve_indicator(id){
        $.ajax({
              url: '/approve_indicator.php',
              type: 'post',
              data: 'id='+id,
              success: function() 
              {
                  alert('success, server says '+output);

                  location.reload();

              }, error: function()
              {
                  alert('something went wrong, rating failed');
              }
        });

}
```

this is the PHP. Not sure if it matters

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$update_indicator = $con->preapre("UPDATE indicators SET approved = ? WHERE indicator_id = ?");
$update_indicator->execute(array(1,$id));
```

Comment: "An error". What error?

Comment: The error message of the approve_indicator(id) function : alert('something went wrong, rating failed');

Comment: This should tell you to use proper error handlers instead of those generic ones. jQuery provides you 3 helpful parameters for `error`.

Comment: Regardless the message - the ajax request is defaulting to the "error:" condition ... I'm new to AJAX and fairly new to Jquery.

Comment: If those 3 lines are the only lines in `approve_indicator.php`, then unless `$update_indicator->execute(array(1,$id));` echoes something, the `$.ajax` success condition will never happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP code contains `preapre` instead of `prepare`. This is likely giving you unwanted results. Also, using a web tool such as Firebug lets you see the AJAX responses. If your PHP errors are displayed, the response will tell you what is wrong with your PHP code.

Comment: Did you look into using a web developer tool to see what the actual response is?

Comment: I'll try... just something like Inspect Element? How do I check the response?

Comment: In Firebug, you can find it under the Console tab like: http://i.imgur.com/kmeJkj2.png. The exact location might differ per tool though.

Comment: I got it. At first it was an internal server error because i forgot to include the connect file on the other PHP file. Then there was an undefined variable in the script.